# How to insert group in report footer in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a special requirement in crystal report.

I want to show a table records in report footer such as **Notes** like this

1. This is my first note.
2. This is my second note.
3. This is my third note.

But as I know, it's not possible to insert group in report footer.

Any help will be appreciable....

Comment: Why do you need a group..how notes is stored in database

Comment: Create a subreport to display notes and show it in the footer

Comment: Hi @Siva notes stored in database in a detail table. That's why I need to group all of them

Comment: If there is only sin record for every note then take a sub report in report footer and place the note in detail of sub report